# alternative methods of hosting a java socket

Tags: java, php, sockets, web, host

In recent discussions on stackoverflow I have discovered that many/most web hosts dont allow java servers to be uploaded as they open ports and create a vulnerability in their system. Without paying extra for a java web host, how is possible to by pass this issue?  Can php be used to somehow wrap the java programmed socket, or even write the socket itself in php? This is one method I have heard, but surely the host would look at this no differently than a java written socket- a security threat?

Whilst i'm on topic, how is it that paying more for a java webhost all of a sudden makes their system less vulnerable? Is this just a con to extort a little more by allowing ports to be open if your willing to pay for it, or is their something that i'm misunderstanding?

Thanks

Comment: I would go for a vps then you have the freedom of choice to do what you want. There are allot of cheap vps hosts for $10 out there. Also with regards to the PHP, no this is not possible. Unless you can run ssh into the shared host and run your php script like php myscript.php but even then again I am not to sure wrapping java server in php never done or heard it myself.

Comment: Please do not ask multiple diverse questions. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @ DavidPostill, point taken. Its just using this site on a mobile is a pain in the ass, s I thought id get it all out.

Comment: @Ludjer, Thats interesting. When you say freedom, you mean I can upload my java server and open whatever ports I want? Supposing someone wanted to access my webspace on a vpn through a port. Will that not get the company who hosts the server pissed. Or will they not worry as their other customers are on different servers and when I leave, a potentially accessed server can be rebooted?

Comment: @dazbrad They dont care what you do to your server as long as it does not break their TOS(eg no porn, no warez, no cp). But majority of the vps hosts i have come along if you want to run a unsecured port open on your server they honestly dont care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Host it using a dedicated or VPS(virtual private server) below are 2 of my personal cloud/vps providers that i use. You can look around for more but yeah shared hosting in my opinion is for entry thing or when you don't want to have to worry about the underlying platform. If you have a understanding of linux and managing your own servers then i would go for vps all the way.

http://aws.amazon.com/ and https://www.digitalocean.com/

With regards to the PHP part of the question as I stated in my comment if you have ssh access you can run your PHP script php myscript.php though i am not to sure how you would wrap your java service.

Comment: I have had a little read into vps and it does sound like an option, I don't know php so ill probably give learning that a miss atm. Thanks for the advice, i'll give your links a visit and see wha they have to offer.